# Parsing multipart/form-data using Apache Commons File Upload

Tags: java, scala, jvm, multipartform-data, apache-commons-fileupload

Does Apache Commons File Upload package provides a generic interface to stream parse `multipart/form-data` chunks via `InputStream`, appending `Array<Byte>`, or via any other generic streaming interface?

I know they have a streaming API but the example only shows you how to do that via `ServletFileUpload`, which I reckon must be specific to `Servlet`.

If not, are there any other alternative frameworks in JVM that lets you do exactly this? Sadly, the framework that I am using, Spray.io, doesn't seem to provide a way to do this.

Comment: What kind of InputStream do you have? Or how do you get it? Apache Commons File Upload has a [FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(RequestContext)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.html#getItemIterator(org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext)) that you can possibly use

Comment: Have you seen this example from the spray.io library? https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/FileUploadHandler.scala

Comment: I will be receiving the input in chunks of Array<Bytes>, so most ideally I would want to feed these bytes to the stream parser. However, the function you mentioned takes a RequestContext whose subclass is only ServletRequestContext and PortletRequestContext. Not general enough for me.

Comment: Yes I did and found out that it doesn't do extraction of the actual data, i.e., the resulting output will still wrapped within the boundary and headers.

Comment: You can make your own implementation of `RequestContext` but you would need to know the characterEncoding, the contentType and the contentLength - do you have access to that in your request?

Comment: Yes. What is the best practice to create a new RequestContext implementation with those informations?

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing similar issue.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne I use this instead: https://github.com/DanielN/multipart-handler

Comment: @lolski Thanks. I will look into this. How did you create an InputStream from your array of Bytes ?

Answer (score 3):

[bayou.io](http://bayou.io) has a generic [MultipartParser](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/mime/MultipartParser.html)

You might need some adapters to work with it, since it has its own 
[Async](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/async/Async.html)
and [ByteSource](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/bytes/ByteSource.html) 
interfaces.

The following example shows how to use the parser synchronously with `InputStream`

```
    String msg = ""
        //+ "preamble\r\n"
        +"--boundary\r\n"
        +"Head1: Value1\r\n"
        +"Head2: Value2\r\n"
        +"\r\n"
        +"body.body.body.body."

        +"\r\n--boundary\r\n"
        +"Head1: Value1\r\n"
        +"Head2: Value2\r\n"
        +"\r\n"
        +"body.body.body.body."

        +"\r\n--boundary--"
        + "epilogue";

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    ByteSource byteSource = new InputStream2ByteSource(is, 1024);
    MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(byteSource, "boundary");
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            MultipartPart part = parser.getNextPart().sync();   // async -> sync
            System.out.println("== part ==");
            System.out.println(part.headers());
            ByteSource body = part.body();
            InputStream stream = new ByteSource2InputStream(body, Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            drain(stream);
        }
        catch (End end) // control exception from getNextPart()
        {
            System.out.println("== end of parts ==");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: email me if you have questions.