# how to read a multipart/mixed response from xquery in java using httpclient?

Tags: java, multipart, apache-commons-httpclient

I want to read a multipart/mixed content-type response returned from xquery in java. I am using http client in java to call/execute the xquery. In java i can able to get only the response body as string or stream or byte content. I want to separate the parts of the multipart response in java using existing multipart APIs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387603/parsing-multipart-form-data-using-apache-commons-file-upload/30403389#30403389

Comment: This really doesn't seem to be related to XQuery. You could be trying to read this multipart response from any Web Server.

Comment: This indeed has nothing to do with XQuery.  The question should be rephrased as: "How can I consume a multipart response with the Apache HTTP Client, version 4?"  Adapt the version accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Apache HTTP Client does not support such a multipart response.  But you can use MIME4J for instance to parse it.  The class [org.expath.httpclient.impl.MultipartResponseBody](https://github.com/fgeorges/expath-http-client-java/blob/master/http-client-java/src/org/expath/httpclient/impl/MultipartResponseBody.java) does exactly that (look at the function `analyzeParts`).